# Include "no-color" option in node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've made a node script and have prettified its output by using colors in my `console.logs`:

```
const noColorOption = args[1] === '--no-color' || args[2] === '--no-color';
const colors = {
    green: noColorOption ? '' : '\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m',
    cyanRed: noColorOption ? '' : '\x1b[36m%s\x1b[91m%s\x1b[0m'
};

// ... examples of console.logs in my script ...
console.log(colors.cyanRed,
  filename + '\n   ',
  redundantModules.join('\n   '));
console.log(colors.green, `\nTotal files searched: ${totalFilesSearched}`);
```

However, the `--no-color` option doesn't work as intended because the `console.log` just prints out the empty string as a space instead.

Should I just add new `console.logs` with no first argument or is there a way to assign the `--no-color` option to make it properly just print out in the default color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%s` instead of empty string.

```
const noColorOption = process.argv[2] === '--no-color';
const colors = {
    green: noColorOption ? '%s' : '\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m',
    cyanRed: noColorOption ? '%s' : '\x1b[36m%s\x1b[91m%s\x1b[0m'
};


console.log(colors.cyanRed, __filename + '\n   ');
console.log(colors.green, `Total files searched: 0`);
```